# Chromium and Chrome conflict within start command

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, windows-registry, chromium

I have both Ungoogled Chromium and Chrome installed on my Windows system.
I have some batch script launching certain profiles in Google Chrome using the `start chrome` command, with flags.

Since I installed Chromium, it seems that my `start chrome` command now opens Chromium.

I went into regedit to check my app paths into `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`, and there doesn't seem to be any issue here because the Google Chrome path seems to correctly point to the right executable.

I even created a path to Chromium to try to "counter" that strange behaviour, but it didn't seem to fix it.
Is there anything else I need to check in the registry in order to fix that odd behaviour?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try `where chrome` in a command prompt, what does it print?

Comment: It prints `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).`

Answer (score 1):

Fixed my issue.  There indeed was a conflict in my registry.

Had to delete an entry in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` that was conflicting with what I had in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`